# Continuity of $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} xy & \text{if} \ xy >0 \\ 0 & \text{if} \ xy \leq 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Where is the following function continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
      xy & \text{if} \  xy >0 \\
       0 & \text{if} \ xy \leq 0
\end{cases}$

Is it continuous on positive values of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What is unclear to you?

Comment: On positive values of $x$ and $y$, the function is $xy$, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes it is. I see that it is continuous for x,y>0 because it is defined as xy which is continuous. But also it is continuous if xy<0 since the function is 0. Isn't that the case? I guess the question is where the function is not continuous?

Comment: Where do the possibilities of discontinuity arise? How would the graph of the function look like if we replace $0$ with $-1$ when $xy \le 0$?

Comment: I cannot visualize it:(. I imagine that there would be a sharp transition at $x,y =0$ which creates a discontinuity. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, both $xy$ and $0$ are continuous functions, hence $f(x,y)$ is continuous for $xy > 0$ and $xy \leq 0.$ Our main concern here is what happens when we transition from $f(x, y) = xy$ to $f(x, y) = 0.$ Observe that this occurs precisely when the sign of $x$ or $y$ changes. Explicitly, we have that $xy > 0$ if and only if $x, y > 0$ or $x, y < 0,$ and likewise, we have that $xy \leq 0$ if and only if $x \leq 0$ and $y > 0$ or $x > 0$ and $y \leq 0,$ so when the sign of $x$ or $y$ changes, then $f(x, y)$ changes.

But in order for either $x$ or $y$ to change sign, there must exist a neighborhood in which $|x|$ or $|y|$ is arbitrarily small, hence the distance $|xy - 0|$ must be arbitrarily small, i.e., $f(x, y)$ is continuous.